# COALESCE w/ mySQL when Vaue is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I have the following sql which should return a sum of all values in tbl_userbets or 0 (if Null) for a given user.

```
select userid, COALESCE(SUM(bet),0) as Sum from `tbl_userbets`
where userid in (1289, 1305, 1315) and graded is not null
group by userid
order by userid
```

IDs 1289 and 1305 have no value in tbl_userbets, I'd expect a return of the following

```
userid | Sum
1289   | 0
1305   | 0
1315   | 1000
```

But I'm only getting the return of 1315.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does "IDs 1289 and 1305 have no value in tbl_userbets" mean that there are no records for those ids, or that they have records but the value of bet is null for all of them?

Comment: It could be either or, in this case - they aren't in that table as of now.

Comment: You can't sum something that is not there :) How did you come up with those IDs? Did you just made them up?

Comment: It's somewhat of a long story, but those IDs are related to a user that's logged into my application. Is there anyway around this without having to check if values exists before running that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
select u.userid
, COALESCE(SUM(bet),0) as Sum 
from tbl_users u left join tbl_userbets ub on u.userid = ub.userid
and ub.graded is not null
where u.userid in (1289, 1305, 1315) 
group by u.userid
order by u.userid
```

You'll have to use the correct tablename though.  I just guessed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have one expression inside out. Change this:

```
COALESCE(SUM(bet),0)
```

to this:

```
SUM(COALESCE(bet,0))
```

If you don't do this, a NULL for *any* value for a user in table will result in 0 as the *entire sum* for the record.

As for why the records are missing entirely, there are probably no records at all for them in the bets table. Using an `IN()` expression won't make those results appear. You still need some record to match with. To make this happen, `JOIN` with a table that is guaranteed to have a record for every user in your database.